# Change default split layout

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can use the `Cmd-Opt-O` shortcut key to change the split layout, but I want it to default to horizontal splits. I can't find a setting for this. Does anyone know if this is possible in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **1.25** version there are commands to split editor in 4 directions. Example `keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+\\",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown",
},
```

`workbench.action.splitEditorUp`

`workbench.action.splitEditorDown`

`workbench.action.splitEditorLeft`

`workbench.action.splitEditorRight`

Comment: VS or Word are more intuitive, simply drag the splitor, why can't they make it?